# Symfony 3 - Cannot use $this->renderView() from static function

Tags: php, function, symfony, email, static

I have a file Mails.php who take care to send different mails according to what I pass to him as parameter from my controllers.

The functions of Mails.php are therefore static functions.
In one of them, I have to use, to send an email, this:

```
->setBody($this->renderView("@Pages/swiftmail/CreationCompte/AccepterDemandeCreationCompte.html.twig",array(
 // some variables
)));
```

It is to allow the function to fetch the message in a dedicated twig file.

However, since it's a static function I need to use, I'm forced to replace $ this-> by self ::
But it does not work :

```
->setBody(self::renderView("@Pages/swiftmail/CreationCompte/AccepterDemandeCreationCompte.html.twig",array(
//some variables
)));
```

**EDIT: I have now :**

**Services.yml:**

```
templating:
    class: Site\PagesBundle\Utils\Mails
    arguments: [templating]
```

**Mail.php:**

```
class Mails

{

private $templating;

    public function __construct(\Twig_Environment $templating)
    {
        $this->templating = $templating;
    }

public function sendMail($user,$raisonMail)
    {
        $transport = \Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance();
        $mailer = new \Swift_Mailer($transport);

        // Entête
        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setFrom(array('****' => '***'))
            //->setTo($user->getEmail());
            ->setTo("************")
            ->setCharset('utf-8')
            ->setContentType('text/html');

        switch($raisonMail)
        {
            case 'formulaireInscription':
                // (1) Confirmation de demande d'inscription
                $message->setSubject("Création de votre compte ATELECH prise en compte")
                        ->setBody($this->templating->render("@Pages/swiftmail/CreationCompte/DemandeCreationCompte.html.twig",array(
                            'prenom'=>$user->getPrenom(),
                            'nom'=>$user->getNom(),
                            )));
                break;


//...

}
```

**DefaultController.php:**

```
$templating = new \Twig_Environment;

$mail = new Mail($templating);

$mail->sendMail($user,'formulaireInscription');
```

But I've : [image]

Comment: You  can't user render without call by object of  "templating" service or container.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your answer. I have in parameter my User object

Comment: I've edited my first post

Comment: The `$templating` property is not static. You cannot access it this way. Is there a special reason why the `sendMail()` method is declared as static?

Comment: When I do not put it in static time, I get an error message asking me to put it in static. I am a beginner in Symfony I do not understand everything unfortunately. So I've this error : Error: Call to protected method Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller::renderView() from context 'Site\PagesBundle\Utils\Mails'

Comment: You can make  service and use it instead.

Comment: I am very beginner, I do not understand how to do my service and use it, I looked at a tutorial to make one. I will edit my code to show you, but it does not seem to work

Comment: You have to use $this->templating->renderView(), the service injected in your class. $templating is not static here and your class do not extends de Controller to do this->renderView() directly. That's why you have to inject $templating as dependency. And why static in this sendMail function?

Comment: Using $this->$templating->renderView(), I've : Error: Cannot access empty property

Comment: So, I put this on my services.yml ?

templating:
    class: Site\PagesBundle\Utils\Mails
    arguments: [@templating]

Comment: use render() instead of renderView()

Comment: I will edite my first post to write my current code

Comment: did It work render() instead of renderView()?

Comment: No, with render(), I've Notice: Undefined property: Site\PagesBundle\Controller\DefaultController::$templating

Comment: you have to do $this->templating and not $this->$templating

Comment: The problem is that I've $this->templating and not $this->$templating and I've the error Notice: Undefined property: Site\PagesBundle\Controller\DefaultController::$templating

Comment: The error is about the `DefaultController` class? Did you place the code for rendering the e-mail template in your controller instead of your `Mails` class?

Comment: No no, in my DefaultController, I call the Mail function by " Mail::sendMail($user,$raison);

Comment: Okay, I resolved some problem about this templating, but I've "You must set a loader first." I'll edit my post

Comment: Replace `templating` by `'@templating'` in your services.yaml file, then clear and warmup cache.

Comment: PS : Have a look on FOSUserBundle which does this job.

Comment: The problem is the same by replawing templating by '@templating', I've this error : "You must set a loader first.". I don't see what is it